# share link (facebook) of youtube video with different title and description

Tags: html, facebook, youtube, social-networking

How create in my webpage a share link(Facebook) of youtube video but change the title and description

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to look up at [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

that using by [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) Javascript SDK

Answer (score 0):

To change the feed story of a shared page, you have to update the open graph tags. See the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).